# Python argparse with -- as the value

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to pass `--` as a value to a Python program using argparse without using the equals (=) sign?

The command line arguments that I added to the argparser are defined like below:

```
parser.add_argument('--myarg', help="my arg description")
```

You would use this argument in a program like this:

```
python myprogram.py --myarg value123
```

Is there a way to run this program with -- as the value instead of 'value123'?

i.e

```
python myprogram.py --myarg --
```

Comment: If the action is `store_true`, the option doesn't take *any* argument.

Comment: Even with the equal sign, `--myarg=--` appears to be treated the same as `--myarg --`.

Comment: It produces `Namespace(myarg=[])`.  It's confusing the parser.  Stick with using `--` as the divider, and don't try to confuse `argparse` or your users.  Why do you need to treat this string as an argument?

Comment: --myarg=-- works okay. However in my use case a Java command dispatcher launches a python command line subprocess with a space between argument/values pairs instead of a equals sign. I am not intending to have -- as a argument but rather as a value to --myarg. This is a requirement for specific use case.

Comment: Bug/issues related to '--': http://bugs.python.org/issue13922 http://bugs.python.org/issue14364

Comment: Actually those bug/issues aren't that recent - more than 3 yrs ago.  But as you can see, the handling of '--', especially multiple ones and ones that look like values, has been buggy.  If possible use some other value.  '--' has a special meaning.  Code that depends on current behavior could fail in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it will not be possible to make `argparse` do this natively.  You could pre-process `sys.argv` though, as a non-intrusive workaround.

```
import sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from uuid import uuid4

sentinel = uuid4().hex

def preprocess(argv):
    return [sentinel if arg == '--' else arg for arg in argv[1:]]

def postprocess(arg):
    return '--' if arg == sentinel else arg

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--myarg', help="my arg description", type=postprocess)
args = parser.parse_args(preprocess(sys.argv))
```

Comment: I get `Namespace(myarg=[])` from your code - with or without the =.

Comment: That's kinda the point.  There is no way to get `myarg=[]` except by passing in `--`.  From the python side, you can do with the `myarg` what you want now ...

Comment: `myarg=[]` is what I'd expect for a `nargs='*'` Action, not the default nargs.

Comment: This is really helpful and a good starting point, so thank you. However, as @hpaulj points out, I need the parsed value to equal the string '--' and not a empty list [].

Comment: Right, my goal was to make `--myarg=--` behave the same as `--myarg --` instead of just failing.  If you want to support `nargs='*'` then you have to change `+= '=--'` to something else (and possibly post-process it), but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: Here's a modification of the idea that should work with `nargs='*'` as well.

Comment: The one potential shortcoming of this solution is that for this to work each argument must be set to type=postprocess, otherwise the preprocessed input value -- (a random uuid) is never converted back. Do you know if there is a way to _only_ convert the argument to a random uuid (preprocess) if the argument type is set to postprocess?

Comment: Not exactly.  Only arguments where you are expecting to receive a `--` as input need the special handler.  If you want it automatically on every argument, then subclass `ArgumentParser` and override `add_argument`, or just write a helper function which adds the argument with the special handler.

Comment: Okay, I suppose that if the value `--` is preprocessed for an argument that is not expecting`--` as input, then the random value will not hurt anything, since `--` would be meaningless anyhow. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this hacky one-liner which modifies `sys.argv`:

```py
import sys, argparse

sys.argv = [ ('__' if arg == '--' else arg) for arg in sys.argv ]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A simple test')
parser.add_argument('path', help='Path of file (use `--` to read from stdin)')
args = parser.parse_args()

print('input is', 'stdin' if args.path == '__' else args.path)
```

Output:

```
> python test.py --
input is stdin
> python test.py foo.bar
input is foo.bar
```

Answer (score -1):

Tested in Python 3.8:

Using the equal sign and quotes around the values definitely solves that issue:

```
--myarg="--"
```

Comment: Using Python 3.10, and `--myarg="--"` leaves `parser.myarg` with `[]`.