# How can I get argparse to accept "--" as an argument to an option?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a command-line option that requires an argument.  I would like to be able to supply `"--"` as the argument, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Sample code: (`test-argparse.py`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import sys


def main(argv):
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-x", "--foo", metavar="VALUE", default="",
                    help="Test option.")
    args = ap.parse_args(argv[1:])

    print(args.foo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

All my attempts to try to pass `"--"` as an argument fail:

```
$ test-argparse.py --foo --
usage: test-argparse.py [-h] [-x VALUE]
test-argparse.py: error: argument -x/--foo: expected one argument

$ test-argparse.py --foo -- --
usage: test-argparse.py [-h] [-x VALUE]
test-argparse.py: error: argument -x/--foo: expected one argument

$ test-argparse.py --foo=--
[]

$ test-argparse.py --foo=-- --
usage: test-argparse.py [-h] [-x VALUE]
test-argparse.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --

$ test-argparse.py --foo="--"
[]

$ test-argparse.py '--foo --'
usage: test-argparse.py [-h] [-x VALUE]
test-argparse.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --foo --

$ test-argparse.py -x--
[]

$ test-argparse.py '-x --'
 --
```

The last case is the closest, but it includes the space (and I can't just strip whitespace, because what if I want to allow `" "` as a value?).  Is there any way that I can accomplish this?

That argparse forces argument permutation on clients (leading to unnecessary ambiguity) is very frustrating.

(I am using Python 2.7.12.)

Comment: I'm guessing `--foo="--"`

Comment: @cricket_007 Nope.  Prints `[]`.

Comment: Basically, I think you do need the quotes around your string. Typical bash programs separate the options and the remainder of the arguments with dashes.

Comment: @cricket_007 Still nope.  If you haven't used argparse before, then I'm not sure how much insight you can give; a sane argument parser would allow disabling argument permutation and would recognize that an option that requires an argument should consume the next token.

Comment: I saw a dup of this question not too long ago, but I can't find. The answer was, "you can't do that."

Comment: on linux works for me `--foo=\"--\"` and `--foo='"--"'`

Comment: @furas: If you do that, argparse will put `"--"` into the string with the quotes.

Comment: Okay, I see that this is basically https://bugs.python.org/issue9334

Comment: This came up last month in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685320/python-argparse-with-as-the-value.  I have a comment with a couple of other bug/issue numbers.  The accepted answer was to preprocess `sys.argv` replacing the `--`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python argparse with -- as the value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685320/python-argparse-with-as-the-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally `--foo=--` should work, but the current parser deletes all '--', leaving an empty string in its place, hence the `foo=[]` result.  I proposed a patch a couple of years ago that should have fixed that, but it's caught in the `argparse` backlog.  http://bugs.python.org/issue13922, http://bugs.python.org/issue14364, http://bugs.python.org/issue9571

[Python argparse with -- as the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685320/python-argparse-with-as-the-value) suggests preprocessing `sys.argv` replacing one or more of the `--` with something else.

If you are game for patching your `argparse.py` file (or subclass the `ArgumentParser` class), I could revisit my earlier work and suggest a fix.  The trick is to accept that `=--` but still use the first free `--` as the 'rest-are-positionals' flag (and retain any following `--`).  Unfortunately one method that needs to be patched is nested in a much larger one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific reason that this doesn't work: `--` means "Skip this token and consider the rest of the arguments to be positional, even if they start with a dash."

Many, many programs won't accept `--` as an argument, but they will accept `-`.  The single dash is even a standard way of specifying "Use standard input or output" in place of a filename.

So the best thing you can do for the users of your program is probably to not design it to require `--`, because that's not something that's usually done, and not something that most modern command-line parsing libraries are likely able to parse.

You could use `--` as a positional option, so you could probably support this:

```
--foo -- --
```

If you make `--foo` have `action='store_true'` (i.e. it is an option taking no argument), plus one non-mandatory positional argument.  That will probably work, because the first `--` means "stop processing dashes as options" and the second is a positional argument.

Comment: I understand what `--` is normally used for, and I understand why argparse has problems (because it wants to do argument permutation).  I do not consider that to be an excuse; a token that follows an option that requires an argument should be treated as that option's argument.  Unfortunately, I do not have a choice about allowing `"--"` as an argument; the argument can be an arbitrary string.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Sure, then you can support it as a positional argument.  I added something to my answer explaining how.